# Como mudar o formato da data em java script?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou pegando a data informada pelo usuário, que seleciona de um `datepicker`. No formulário o formato fica exibido certo `dd/mm/yyyy`, mas o problema é quando pego a data pra jogar em uma `variável`, ela vem da seguinte forma:

```
Wed Mar 23 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)
```

Como faço a conversão da `variável` em `yyyy/mm/dd`?

pois vou precisar dessa informação para que seja inserida em meu banco.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crie uma função para isso:

```
function formatarData(data) {
    var d = new Date(data),
        mes = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        dia = '' + d.getDate(),
        ano = d.getFullYear();

    if (mes.length < 2) mes = '0' + mes;
    if (dia.length < 2) dia = '0' + dia;

    return [ano, mes, dia].join('/');
}


alert(formatarData('Wed Mar 23 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)'));
```

Resultado:

> 2016/03/23

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tretaa/nf3hyq81/1/)

Comment: Valeu Marllon, vou tentar.

Comment: Tem outras formas, ok? Se quiser eu edito a resposta e adiciono pra você... mas essa solução, na minha opinião, é a mais simples.